# How to make textures look worn?

Tags: texturing

So far, most of the textures i've been using seems very "new" and polished. For example, in the real world, a wood floor is not bright and shiny and over times it becomes more worn.

Therefore, i was wondering if anybody knew a way to make a wood texture and textures in general more worn?

I have attached two pictures to illustrate my point:

1. A woodfloor texture that looks bright and new
2. A real world wood floor that looks worn

Its clear that the two wood floors arent looking the same

Tips and tricks would be much appreciated :-)!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use a voronoi texture, make the scale very large, so that at least 20 or so spots are in you your floor, use a coloramp and bring white and black closer to grey, otherwise it will be very glossy and not glossy at all in some places. Then, you invert the voronoi texture, plug it into the roughness, and you got a smudged floor

Comment: You can also download texture from websites like sketchfab and polligon to get roughness maps, which do the work for you

Answer (score 5):

The material you provided is just a Base Color texture, so it is worth quickly noting that a lot of the character of the floor in the photo is created by surface imperfections.  You'll get these from the *Roughness*, *Normal Map*, and *Height* textures in the PBR workflow.  Still, your question is about wear and tear, which is not exactly the same thing.

I have three pretty basic methods for this.  The first is simply the *Hue/Saturation* node.

[image]

Apply this to the *Base Color* and you can desaturate an object as though it sat in the sun too long, or darken an object as a whole with the *Value* setting.

The second is to make use of the *Ambient Occlusion* map.  Ambient Occlusion is normally used to tell us where objects in the scene are close to each other, and thus would most likely be in shadow.  You can, however, use the output for whatever you like.  So we could say if two objects are close to each other it's also kind of a place where detritus will build.

There are lots of ways to control the output, but in this example I used a *Color Ramp* to find a suitable map to use as a *Factor* input on a *Hue/Saturation* node.  It's used to put grime in the mortar between these pieces in a stone floor.

[image]

On the left base color only, on the right this node group.

[image]

My third method would be to use a surface imperfection image texture.  You can probably find them the same place you get your other image textures.  [Here are some examples.](https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures?search=&resolution=1&category=Surface%20Imperfections&color=any&page=1)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, i'll look into that :-)!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to give something a rough look:

1. To use a roughness and normal map(most of the times available on the same website as the texture).
2. To create some surface imperfections to create a worn-out look using noise.

If you don't have a roughness or a normal map, you can make some using color ramps and bump nodes(like in the screenshots).

Screenshots:
[image: This render is done just using the image that you provided]
This render is done just using the image that you provided
[image]

Node Group

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, i'll look into that :-)!

Comment: Hey, I made a tiny mistake in the node setup. The first image texture should be set to SRGB. Rest everything is good.