# My render doesn't quite look right and I'm not sure what it is

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, photorealism

I'm not sure if I can ask this kind of question here and if not then I will delete it, but I've been having trouble with rendering my scene. I use Cycles, 512 samples, plenty of light bounces, 5 film exposure, and default color management. Still, this render looks distinctly computer-generated. All the materials are, at least in my opinion, photorealistic, so it must be the lighting or maybe composition? I'm not exactly sure which is why I want some help. Any ideas?

[image: render itself]

Comment: maybe try to add volumetric? Also a bit of bloom so that your neon are not completely square?

Comment: I think it's just a lack of clutter. Strikes me as odd that you have a room with just one thing in it like that - and the one object you have is too perfect. Add some boxes or something in the background maybe? Or have some of the wall paint chipping off/aged.

Comment: No 'backstory'. Look _really hard_ at references online and in your neighbourhood. Note features, OK. But go one step further. Work out how the features got there _Why_ they are exactly as they are / where they are.

Comment: You are seeing the 'perlin noise'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brain is sensing the 'sameness' of all of the color variation you've introduced through the use of the *Noise Texture* node.

[image]

You simply need more layers and variation in size and frequency to break up the slightly regular pattern that perlin noise produces.

Here's a pretty simple example with some randomness built in for each individual object the shader is put on.  Some color ramps would go a long way to make the effect more noticeable.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216331/110840

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is with the composition of the scene.

check this video:[Blender Guru Understanding Composition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8i7OKbWmRM&t=3s)